# Error indicator for std::iterator

Tags: c++, stl, c++03

I require a good substitute of `std::string::npos` for `std::iterator` which is has no relation to "next position after last valid address" (`end`).

Here is some background:

I have a method, where I need to find a certain value between two iterators and return iterator to a position NEXT to it (which may or may not be `end`). It may happen that the method call is just a dummy and no action is required - in this case we simply return `begin`. I also need some indication that we were unable to find the value in question and here lies the crux of the matter: I don't know how to indicate it.

Here is a simple example:

```
class FinderClass
{
    public:
    FinderClass(uint8_t* byte): byte_(byte) {}
    std::iterator findEndOfFrame(std::iterator begin, std::iterator end) 
    {
        if (byte_ == NULL)
        {
            return byte_;
        }

        std::iterator result = std::find(begin, end, *byte_);

        if (result != end)
        {
            return ++result;
        }

        return ???;
    }

    private:
    uint8_t* byte_;
}
```

And somewhere down the line we may use it this way:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> myVector;
myVector.push_back(1);
myVector.push_back(2);
myVector.push_back(3);

uint8_t val = 2;
FinderClass finder(&val);
std::iterator result = finder.findEndOfFrame(myVector.begin(), myVector.end());

if (/* no error */)
{
    size_t len = std::distance(myVector.begin(), result);
}
```

In this case expected value of `len` is 2. Had `val`'s value was set to `3` expected result would be 3 and in case of 4 - error. `0` is only appropriate result if NULL was provided in constructor.

Please keep in mind, that this is a very simplified version of more complex architecture. In reality, I cannot simply check what was provided in the constructor, since it is separated by multiple abstraction layers and the real `FinderClass` implements an interface (and it's rather bizzare implementation, because in other implementation there is no option for NULL value for `byte_`). At the point where we call `std::distance` only a pointer to superclass is available.

I also do not use `std::iterator` itself, but a derivative class, but since `std::iterator` does not have some sort of `npos` value defined, I thought that there is probably a good reason for it, so I didn't do it myself either. I only used `std::iterator` in this example for simplicity.

**So summing up**: if `end` cannot be used to indicate an error, what should be used instead?

Several considerations:

1. Exceptions are forbidden by team's coding standards
2. Changes in interface (for example to change returned value to a pointer to `std::iterator` and simply return NULL on error) are considered "nuclear option, since it would require updating many other implementations and their unit tests.
3. C++11 is not avaialable

Comment: wrap an iterator in another iterator-like class with added logic,e.g. implement comparision against MyIterator::npos? Also ++end is UB..

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It should be `++result`

Comment: There are n+1 valid iterators in a string of length n, but you want to return n+2 possible results. Though you can of course invent your own type that can take n+2 values, it cannot be made into a full fledged iterator and it will fail if used with some standard algorithms. Why not return a `pair<bool, iterator>` or `optional<iterator>` instead?

Comment: I wanted to avoid it because of the second point in "considerations" - changing interface was supposed to be last ditch resort, as it would require changing many other classes and their unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code using iterators is usually (and arguably should) pretty much agnostic of the actual type of iterator and instead just expects something with, roughly, incrementing and dereferencing operators. You don't specify whether the iterator has to be of a specific type or not, if not it's relatively easy to return a wrapper around an actual vector iterator which itself implements iterator behavior and also the extra functionality of having an invalid state. As said in the other answers though, going for optional<> is probably a better choice if possible as it clearly expresses what you actually mean. Anyway, pseudocode:

```
//template argument is the actual iterator type
template< class Iter >
class iterator : std::iterator< Iter::iterator_category,
                                Iter::value_type, .... >
{
public:
  enum tag { invalid_tag };

  //construct the invalid 'error' iterator
  iterator( invalid_tag ) :
    error( true )
  {}

  //construct actual iterator
  iterator( Iter iter ) :
    error( false ),
    iter( iter )
  {}

  //forward all functions
  reference operator * ()
  {
    assert( valid() );
    return *iter;
  }

  ....

  //check validity
  bool valid() const
  {
    return !error;
  }

private:
  bool error;
  Iter iter; 
};
```

Comment: While I agree that optional<> would be a good choice as well, this solution turned out to fit slightly better into overall architecture, which is why this is accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given the constraints, I would either return a `boost::optional<Iterator>` or a pointer to the next element (in which case you can return `NULL` if there is no next element).

`optional` is more expressive and safer of course, and requires less gerrymandering to convert the result back into an iterator.